# Upgrade form froyo to jellybean

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 4.1-jelly-bean

I recently upgraded by Samsung galaxy exhibit 2 to jelly bean 4.2.2 from gingerbread. I was wondering if it was also possible for my Samsung dart, running on Froyo. Can i flash the same ROM? Is it the same process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ROMs are device specific. So: No, you cannot flash the ROM from your Exhibit on your Dart without most likely breaking the latter.